# How long does the SpaceChem demo last?

Tags: spacechem

I'm on level 3-2 (Danopth, Split Before Bonding) of the SpaceChem demo. When does the demo end? The [official website](http://www.spacechemthegame.com/) doesn't have any info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The demo ends when you complete World 3 (as World 4 won't unlock). You have more than a hour left of gameplay; those levels aren't easy.